# Display database fields as multiple select checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code which i am trying to use in order to diplay table column names as checkbox values, i mean something liek this:

```
$section = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forma");  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($section)){
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='" . $firstrow[''] . "' />";

}
```

I have it in the wrong way, but how should i do in order to print column names as checkboxes, in an automatic way, not manually.

How to reach it using PDO?

> $q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE forma"); 
>   $q->execute(); $table_fields
>   = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

Thanks

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Hey, thanks, i'll try to use PDO.. is just that now i came to become familiar with mysql_ and then i need to switch so fast :)

Comment: Just double-checking: You`re not interested in the values/records of table `forma` but the column names i.e. the names that show up as the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`forma\``?

Comment: i just need to display all the column names of forma, as checkboxes, and when i click on the checkbox, what i need to insert in the database is the name of the column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreword: The MySQL extension is marked as deprecated, better use mysqli or [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo)

---

Though there are functions like [mysql_field_name](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php) or [SHOW COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-columns.html) I'd suggest using the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) as it gives you more flexibility.

```
<?php
$database = 'test';
$table = 'forma';

$mysql = mysql_connect('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test', $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql)); // selecting db is not not necessary in this case

$query = sprintf("
    SELECT
        COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = '%s'
        AND TABLE_NAME = '%s'
",
    mysql_real_escape_string($database),
    mysql_real_escape_string($table)
);
$result = mysql_query($query, $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));

while( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) ) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['COLUMN_NAME']);
    $type = htmlspecialchars($row['COLUMN_TYPE']);
    printf("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"col[]\" value=\"%s\" />%s (%s)<br />\r\n", $name, $name, $type);
}
```

same thing using PDO

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT
        COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = :database
        AND TABLE_NAME = :table
');
$stmt->execute( array('database'=>'test', 'table'=>'forma') );
foreach( $stmt as $row ) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['COLUMN_NAME']);
    $type = htmlspecialchars($row['COLUMN_TYPE']);
    printf("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"col[]\" value=\"%s\" />%s (%s)<br />\r\n", $name, $name, $type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through all columns like this for example:

```
$firstrow = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($section)){
    if (!$firstrow) {
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='" . $column . "' />"; 
        }
        $firstrow = true;
    }
}
```

I hope i understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes you did and it was great :)
could you help me with something?
using PDO as someone suggested can you see my updated question?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) with PDO:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost', 'username', 'passwqord');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$result = $dbh->query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM forma');

if($result)
{
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['Field']) . "' />";
    }
}
```

The same result can be retrieved with `DESCRIBE forma` instead of `SHOW COLUMNS`.